Google Pagespeed Insights not detailing performance issues
I tested a website today 4/10/24 and Google Pagespeed Insights is not longer detailing all the performance issues on the site.
There is no Performance section on any url I tested. The first detail section it lists is Accessibility.
I can't find anything in search about this.
Does anyone know if they removed that and didn't announce it?
Or is this a glitch? Seems like if it was a glitch - the section would appear, but there would be no data.
There is no performance detail section - when there was just a few days ago.

This looks like a bug. Escalating internally.

Thanks, Mr. Pollard. I love your product and use it several times a day. It makes my job as a performance specialist so much easier. I freaked out a little bit. I don't know how I would do without that detail performance analysis! Thank you for your quick response and your product.

Rolling out the fix now. Should be fixed soon. Thanks for raising this!

And we're back!

This was a bug. We're rolling out a fix now.
FYI, I happened to see this one but in future it would be best to report issues like this in the Lighthouse repo (it's the same team that works on PSI): https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues
